# Re-arranging the order of div elements for mobile users

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

Our site has a sub-navigation on each page in the left column. The content on that page is then loaded in the right column while the sub-menu stays the same. This works great for desktop users, but for mobile users, the user has to scroll to get to the content because of this sub-menu.
So what we want, is to re-position this sub-menu, for mobile users, and move it after the content. Sort of just swithing the sorting order of the left and right column.

Utill now, I've declared a couple of classes that hides/displays the element according to screen-size usinge css media queries. This works, but we have to multiply the sub-menu. Is there an easier way of doing so? - that is cross-browser compatible?

**UPDATE**
Here's the html for the page:

```
<div class="grid">
    <aside class="grid_3">
        <div class="grid_w100 img"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
        <div class="grid_w100 pageMenu"><ul>...</ul></div><!--  tablet and above  -->
    </aside>
    <article class="grid_9">
        <h1>heading</h1>
        <p>...</p>
    </article>
    <div class="grid_w100 pageMenu"><ul>...</ul></div><!--  mobile only  -->
</div>
```

The goal was to just have one `pageMenu`-container - the first one located inside the `aside` tag, and just reposition it to show after the `article` for mobile users only.

Comment: You could do this with javascript, but we will need to see your current code.

Comment: Try hiding the submenu off-screen and let it appear when the user presses a button. I highly doubt that the user needs access to the submenu all the time he's on your page.

Comment: If all the elements need to be visible in your mobile version, you might re-arrange the order so the main content technically comes first as far as HTML is concerned, but float the menu left in your desktop version. remove that style in your mobile version with a CSS media query to have the main content back in first place.

Answer (score 0):

@Ben Phillip has the right idea. Here's how it would be done in Bootstrap.

http://jsfiddle.net/oakley808/ttumsbpe/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3">
         <h1>Heading</h1>

        <p>Article</p>
        <p>Article</p>
        <p>Article</p>
        <p>Article</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9">
        <img src="//placehold.it/300x100/003366" class="img-responsive hidden-xs" />
         <h3>Menu</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>item1</li>
            <li>item2</li>
            <li>item3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```